# tic tac toe but x cant win (python, tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

so I'm making a Tic tac Toe game application to learn more about Tkinter and it relatively works except for the fact that x can't win! I've coded o and x identically but x won't register. had to cut off most of the code because of stack overflow so btn means button and flag is a count as well as click which is what I used for going from x to o.

**code:**

```
def btnClick(btns):
   global click, flag, player2_name, player1_name, playerb, pa
   if btns["text"] == " " and click == True:
       btns["text"] = "X"
       click = False
       p1wins = player1_name.get() + "wins!"
       p2wins = player2_name.get() + "wins!"
       win()
       flag += 1


   elif btns["text"] == " " and click == False:
       btns["text"] = "O"
       click = True
       win()
       flag += 1
   else:
       tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Tic-Tac-Toe", "Button already Clicked!")


def disableButton():
   btn1.configure(state=DISABLED)
   btn2.configure(state=DISABLED)
   btn3.configure(state=DISABLED)
   btn4.configure(state=DISABLED)
   btn5.configure(state=DISABLED)
   btn6.configure(state=DISABLED)
   btn7.configure(state=DISABLED)
   btn8.configure(state=DISABLED)
   btn9.configure(state=DISABLED)

def win():
   if (flag == 8):
       tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Tic-Tac-Toe", "It is a Tie")


   elif (btn1['text'] == 'x' and btn2['text'] == 'x' and btn3['text'] == 'x' or
         btn4['text'] == 'x' and btn5['text'] == 'x' and btn6['text'] == 'x' or
         btn7['text'] == 'x' and btn8['text'] == 'x' and btn9['text'] == 'x' or
         btn1['text'] == 'x' and btn5['text'] == 'x' and btn9['text'] == 'x' or
         btn3['text'] == 'x' and btn5['text'] == 'x' and btn7['text'] == 'x' or
         btn1['text'] == 'x' and btn2['text'] == 'x' and btn3['text'] == 'x' or
         btn1['text'] == 'x' and btn4['text'] == 'x' and btn7['text'] == 'x' or
         btn2['text'] == 'x' and btn5['text'] == 'x' and btn8['text'] == 'x' or
         btn7['text'] == 'x' and btn6['text'] == 'x' and btn9['text'] == 'x'):
       disableButton()
       tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Tic-Tac-Toe", "congrats %s!!" % (player1_name.get()))


   elif (btn1['text'] == 'O' and btn2['text'] == 'O' and btn3['text'] == 'O' or
         btn4['text'] == 'O' and btn5['text'] == 'O' and btn6['text'] == 'O' or
         btn7['text'] == 'O' and btn8['text'] == 'O' and btn9['text'] == 'O' or
         btn1['text'] == 'O' and btn5['text'] == 'O' and btn9['text'] == 'O' or
         btn3['text'] == 'O' and btn5['text'] == 'O' and btn7['text'] == 'O' or
         btn1['text'] == 'O' and btn2['text'] == 'O' and btn3['text'] == 'O' or
         btn1['text'] == 'O' and btn4['text'] == 'O' and btn7['text'] == 'O' or
         btn2['text'] == 'O' and btn5['text'] == 'O' and btn8['text'] == 'O' or
         btn7['text'] == 'O' and btn6['text'] == 'O' and btn9['text'] == 'O'):
       disableButton()
       tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Tic-Tac-Toe", "congrats %s!!" % (player2_name.get()))
```

Comment: You're setting `X` and checking for `x`. These characters are not identical.

Comment: BTW, instead of `btn1` / `btn2` / etc, consider having a list of buttons, so it's `btns[0]`, `btns[1]`, etc; that way you can loop over them programatically (`for btn in btns: btn.configure(state=DISABLED)`)

Comment: ...similarly, you could loop your other checks that way instead of needing to write them out by hand. (Example for the horizontal direction: `for row in (0,1,2): if btns[row*3+0]['text'] == btns[row*3+1] == btns[row*3+2] and btns[row*3]['text'] != " ": reportWin(btns[row*3]['text']); break`) -- that also lets you only do one comparison pass, instead of one for `X`s and another for `O`s).